# Change selected XML Node

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I am trying to do WCF library application. I'm stuck with borrow a book part. 
I want to iterate through all nodes in `<book>` and need edit an "userid" node, which has an "id" same as a parameter of my function, tried to do something like that.

My XML Structure

```
<catalog>
  <book>
    <id>bk101</id>
    <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
    <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
    <userid>789</userid>
  </book>
  <book>
    <id>bk102</id>
    <title>Midnight Rain</title>
    <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
    <userid>720</userid>
  </book>
  <book>
    <id>bk103</id>
    <title>Testowa</title>
    <author>TESTTT, test</author>
    <userid>666</userid>
  </book>
  <book>
    <id>bk105</id>
    <title>qwertyuiop</title>
    <author>Qwe, Asd</author>
    <userid></userid>
  </book>
</catalog>
```

Function to borrow a book (for now, just trying to set hardcoded value there)

```
public void borrowBook(string s)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("SampleDB.xml");
    XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
    XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("catalog/book");
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        if (node.Attributes["id"].Value.Equals(s))
        {
            node.Attributes["userid"].Value = "new value";
        }
    }
    db.Save("SampleDB.xml");
}
```

Client part:

```
BookServiceReference.BookServiceClient client = 
new BookServiceReference.BookServiceClient();
BookServiceReference.Book[] x = client.borrowBook("bk101");
```

Comment: What is your question? Is something not working the way you expected, or do you want us to guess?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sample the root element (or document element) is the `catalog` element so doing `XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement; XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("catalog/book");` will never select anything. And of course your XML structure has elements like `book` with child elements like `id` or `userid` but no attributes so you rather want to use code like

```
foreach (XmlElement book in doc.SelectNodes(string.Format("catalog/book[id = '{0}']", s))
{
  book["userid"].InnerText = "new value";
}
```